# Org Chart Software

Tags: charts

I'm looking for software to display our companies employee organization structure. That is, a tree like structure where the CEO would be at the top of the tree and then all other employees would branch off from there. Don't really have a cost limit, just want to see what's out there.

**A few features I'm looking for:**

- Windows compatible! Web-Apps are fine, too.
- Ability to add pictures for each node in the chart
- The ability to search for names & keywords that would filter results in the chart
- SQL Server connection
- We have a database containing all employees and their employee ID, as    well as their supervisor's employee ID, so ideally the software
  would be able to auto-populate the structure of the chart using our
  current data or by using a slightly modified version of our data

Comment: Reading between the lines: it should be for Windows? Would a web-app be acceptable as well? How about costs (if any)?

Comment: Yes, windows sorry. Just want to see what's out there, so no cost limit. Web-apps are fine!

Answer (score 3):

If a programmatic solution is acceptable [Essential Diagram for JavaScript/Angular](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including Org Charts. Here is an [example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/mi2u0kdo).

There is an equivalent solution available for [WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/diagram) if you prefer to build a Windows solution.
[image: Organization chart]

- Platform: Web, Windows (both are available)
- Ability to add pictures for each node in the chart: Yes. [Example](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/diagram/organizationalchart/team)
- The ability to search for names & keywords: Yes. Can be implemented as the Diagram can display a subset of the nodes
- SQL Server connection: Yes
- Use existing data: Yes. The controls support data binding and can be bound to your data.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this looks very promising! I'll send it up the chain!

Answer (score 0):

[OrgChart JS](https://balkangraph.com/) lets developers to create simple, flexible and highly customizable organization chart for presenting structural data in an elegant way

[Tutorial: How to create OrgChart JS using MS SQL database and ASP.NET MVC](https://github.com/BALKANGraph/OrgChartWebApp/blob/master/README.md)

It support all features that you are looking for

[image]